# Material TextView via Storyboard?

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

Is there a way to implement the material TextView via the storyboard? The example only shows via programmatically. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part about using a TextView in storyboards with the Material Text class that does pattern detection is the instantiation part. Storyboards take care of the initialization for you, which makes it difficult to update the textContainer layer, as it needs to be passed to the TextView when initialized. I am looking into this to see if there is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually quite simple, and I just discovered it myself while attempting to do what you asked. All you need to do is go to the identity inspector of whatever object you want to use as a material object, then in the "class" field, put the ID of whatever material class you're using (i.e. "RaisedButton"), and you're all set! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/blob/master/Sources/TextField.swift) of `TextField`, you will see that it is a subclass of `UITextField`. This means that you can just change the class of a `UITextField` object that you drop onto your Storyboard, and then do any other configuration in code.